# Steam isn't launching

Tags: steam

so I installed steam and when I opened it the first time it updated successfully
and then when I tried to launch it the second time it appears on the taskbar the it vanished 
and everytime I try to open it it just appear in the taskbar the it vanish 
I tried to uninstall it and install it from terminal then uninstall it and install it from muon and it doesn't fixed the problem 
can anybody help me please :(
and sorry for bad english.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu with kubuntu-desktop installed

Comment: Mention the version of Ubuntu as well.

Comment: version 18.04 LTS

Comment: any output when you run steam from the command line?

Comment: nothing it just appear at the taskbar then it disappear after a seconds

Comment: So after removing kubuntu, installing steam .deb file from steam, and installing steam launcher from ubuntu software app
and now everytime I try to open steam theres a error pop up appear and it says "Couldn't set up Steam data - please contact technical support"